# Как изменить цвет скролл ползунка?

Tags: html, css

Пишу вот это:

```
 scrollbar-face-color: #33b5e5;
```

в

```
 <div id="my_favorite">    
   <div id="favorite_list">
      <div id="song_cover1"></div>
          <div id="song_frame1"></div>
       <div id="song_cover2"></div>
           <div id="song_frame2"></div>
       <div id="song_cover3"></div>
           <div id="song_frame3"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

где:

```
    #my_favorite {
   background-color:#F5F5F5;
       overflow:scroll;
   scrollbar-face-color: #33b5e5;
    }
```

но ничего не происходит. Все по старому

Comment: а как на остальных браузерах сделать???

Comment: вопрос решен. Как закрыть вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос не закрывается. Если вам тут ответили отмечайте правильныйответ и все

Answer (score 1):

Только **IE6+** поддерживает это свойство. Плюс должен быть контент для скролла и фиксированный размер div'a.

Comment: ну я понял. У меня появляется обычный скролл. Хочу придать свой дизайн ему. Изменить толщину и цвет. Как можно сделать?

Comment: Стандартными методами - никак. Если только писать свой на JavaScript или искать готовые плагины для jQuery. Благо такие есть, например: [**jScrollPane**](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/).

Comment: А вообще, есть неплохой обзор подобных плагинов: http://designhuntr.com/custom-jquery-scrollers/

Answer (score 1):

Для webkit'ов так: https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar-button
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner
::-webkit-resizer

:horizontal
:vertical
:decrement
:increment
:start
:end 
:double-button
:single-button
:no-button
:corner-present
:window-inactive
```

А вот для FF не получится.